# How can I view fonts with Ubuntu?

Tags: gratis, linux, font-utility

I would like to view fonts in a way that I can see all elements of the font as well as which code point of the font corresponds to which symbol.

For example, it should be easy to see that symbol 201 is

[image]

in [marvosym](http://www.marvosym.com/download.html).

Please note that the default "Font Viewer" does not allow this. So "Font Viewer" is not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I just found http://bluejamesbond.github.io/CharacterMap/ which looks very nice:

[image]

and `fontmatrix` (in the repository) which looks less nice, but has the index I needed:

[image]